# Is there any official link between Warhammer 40,000 and Event Horizon?

Tags: warhammer-40k, event-horizon

I've read over on TVTropes that many fans consider Event Horizon to be some kind of prequel to the future-set game of Warhammer 40,000 and, in searching the internet, have seen a number of forum posts positing this, but nothing pointing to an official link (or, at least, in the semi-official book universe).

Has there been any official attempt to link the movie into the game's universe?

Comment: I never thought of this, but now you mention it, it is an interesting Q and would certainly seem to flow.

Comment: Interesting question! And regardless of whether or not a connection exists. We can all agree Event Horizon is brilliant!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well this is from the writer’s twitter so:

> **@phubar:** I played the shit out of 40K, so it was definitely an influence, conscious or otherwise.
>
> <sub>[Twitter, phubar, 4 May 2017](https://mobile.twitter.com/phubar/status/860129292151214082)</sub>

Comment: Really nice find! In the future can you quote the important parts of the link in the answer in case the link goes dead. In this case that would be the tweet by Eisner and I have already done it for you.

Answer (score 22):

[*Event Horizon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Horizon_%28film%29) was written by [Philip Eisner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_Eisner) and [Andrew Kevin Walker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Kevin_Walker) and was distributed by [Paramount Pictures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paramount_Pictures).  I can find no real link between Paramount and [Games Workshop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Games_Workshop) nor between the *Event Horizon* writers and the *Warhammer 40K* writers.

Therefore this sounds like an unsubstantiated rumor based on the similarity of the warp drive in *Event Horizon* to the "[warp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warp_%28Warhammer_40000%29)" in WH4K. And the suggestion that one's interstellar starship can get demonically invaded while traveling faster than light.

Personally I always felt the plot of *Event Horizon* seemed close to the plot of [*Doom*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doom_%28video_game%29).

**Much later edit**:  There's a later added answer that mentions that Isner found it to be an influence.  However, the question mentions if Event Horizon is a "prequel" or **"Has there been any official attempt to link the movie into the game's universe?"**.  To which the answer is still, **no**.  There's no "official link" to Warhammer 40K from Event Horizon.  Isner is just admitting he may have subconsciously borrowed (stolen?) the idea of faster than light travel intersecting with a hell-like dimension.

Comment: hmm.. I hadn't really thought about a connection to Doom - but that actually had demons and monsters, while Event Horizon is a demonically possessed ship.

Comment: Yeah, but it follows the plot-line of the search, gone wrong, for an advanced form of FTL travel that happens to intersect with hell for some reason.

Comment: I never really knew the backstory to Doom - I learn something everytime I come here :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the connection between EH and WH40K is purely fan speculation. It's most likely based on the warp drive functionality as well as the idea of a chaotic dimension (which is where the Chaos Marines come from in 40k).

Comment: If the demons or whatever that killed the crew of the Event Horizon were any similar to the daemons in 40K, they would just kill/posses/enslave everyone and everybody on board, make the ship their home, and take a small trip to earth to "stir up some trouble".

Answer (score 2):

Although I cannot yet confirm with hard facts, my understanding is that the creators of Event Horizon were huge 40K fans; the script was intended as a part of the WH40K timeline but they failed to secure the rights from Games Workshop. So... it's not conclusive but there *is* evidence to support the theory. Nevertheless the answer is **no, there is not an official link**, yet there is likely an *un*official one.

Comment: So what is the evidence then? Since you say it exists.

Comment: Testimonial evidence, as indicated above.

Comment: Why should we believe your testimony though if there is nothing to back it up?

Comment: It's not my testimony. It's the testimony of those who supposedly played Warhammer with script writers.

Answer (score 0):

It's a well known creepy pasta. One that I personally subscribed to and the similarly is huge. The comment on how Chaos entities would act isn't accurate as the books and I do read everything I can from black library act in many differing ways. The clearest mental leap is that minor entities "grabbed onto the Event Horizon" during its increasingly short trip in the warp. The humans of the time wouldn't know of the need for shielding or phys for a safe passage and so if the trip was any longer the ship would simply have been lost. As is, the crew was lost with a weak or several weak entities starving and feeding on the souls of the crew and the small team of rescuers. A single warp creature can even survive on a planet for a long time such as on the Lion Johnson's world. 
There's a reason for working without a phy, a protective barrier, the form the entities take, and the way it follows the survivors in the life boat, because yes in my head it came to earth and lived until it phased out of existence or the emperor killed it (head canon again).

Again, look up the story and you will find plenty of evidence that;

1. It's not official canon.
2. Warhammer is very flexible so adding things is really easy.
3. It's said by black library that everything is canon, just not necessarily true.